# excel import plugin is not working with grails 2.2.1

Tags: excel, plugins, import

i want to make use of excel import plugin into my grails project (grails version: 2.2.1)

for this i installed both excel-import:1.0.0 and its dependency plugin joda time 1.4 into my project.

when i run the project with sample data in an excel sheet, i got error as

**"unable to resolve class org.grails.plugins.excelimport.ExcelImportUtils"**.

i thoroughly searched the plugin contents, in that im unable to find the required class: ExcelImportUtils which is the heart of the plugin to perform many functionalities like importing whole excel sheet to populate domain classes.

so please help me how to find this required class in plugin to function properly..

and also i could not find any plugins which suit my requirement. so i have to stick to this plugin only.......

Answer (score 0):

The **"ExcelImportUtils"** has been changed to **"ExcelImportService"**.
So you just have to `import "org.grails.plugins.excelimport.ExcelImportService"` and change `ExcelImportUtils` to `ExcelImportService`.